# How to do spatial autocorrelation for 2 raster data of different spatial resolution

Tags: r, spatial, autocorrelation

How to create spatial autocorrelation map showing the relation between 2 raster data with different spatial resolution?

I am encountering neighborhood list error after resampling and giving moran test command.

As I am new to R language and spatial analysis, i am unable to understand and correct the error. Can anyone please help me with this?

The code which I tried:

```
# Load required packages

library(spdep)
library(raster)

# Load example satellite data

data("elev")
data("prec")

# Create a stack of the two variables
sat_stack <- stack(elev, prec)

# Convert the stack to a SpatialPixelsDataFrame
sat_sp <- as(sat_stack, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

# Check spatial autocorrelation of the satellite data
sat_moran <- moran(sat_sp, listw = nb2listw(knearneigh(coordinates(sat_sp), k = 10)))

#raster1 is not a listw object
#raster2_resampled is not a listw object\`
```

Comment: please edit your code to make it a *minimal, self-contained reproducible* example. That is, create data with code, or use files that ship with R.

Comment: This seems like a moderately challenging problem in spatial statistics, not something that can be solved by an adjustment to the code ... ??

Comment: There is no answer to the question because, by definition, there is no autocorrelation between two variables (rasters). Please edit your question to clarify your objective,  Perhaps you want the local correlation? See `terra::layerCor` and `terra::autocor` for autocorrelation.